# Getting data like name or image of the contact out of ABRecord using ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate

Tags: xcode, swift

I want to give the users of my app the possibility to get their contacts out of their address book. 
I can present the ABPeoplePickerNavigationController and the user can select a person and then the ABPPNC dismiss again.

Thats the code I used to present it:

```
    let peopleController = ABPeoplePickerNavigationController()
    peopleController.delegate = self
    peopleController.predicateForSelectionOfPerson = NSPredicate(value: true)
    self.presentViewController(peopleController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

And the peoplePickerNavigationController didSelectPerson function is called but I don't get how to get Information out of the person of type ABRecord. At https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AddressBookUI/Reference/ABPeoplePickerNavigationController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Address_Book_Properties Apple says there are some Address Book Properties like: ABPersonNamePrefixProperty or ABPersonMiddleNameProperty but I don't get how to work with it.

So basically I want to do something like this:

```
func peoplePickerNavigationController(peoplePicker: ABPeoplePickerNavigationController!, didSelectPerson person: ABRecord!) {

    // What I want to do:
    let name = person.lastName
    let firstName = person.firstName
    let image = person.image
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a long search I found an answer that worked for me:

```
    func peoplePickerNavigationController(peoplePicker: ABPeoplePickerNavigationController!, didSelectPerson person: ABRecord!) {

    var firstName: String?
    if   ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty) != nil{
        firstName = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty).takeRetainedValue() as? String
    }
    var lastName: String?
    if ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty){
        lastName = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty).takeRetainedValue() as? String
    }

    var pImage: UIImage?
    if person != nil && ABPersonHasImageData(person){
        pImage = UIImage(data: ABPersonCopyImageData(person).takeRetainedValue())

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

it would be easy if you use "ABAddressBookRef" and get all contacts . then you can show it to user as you want and will help in future too.